# Can I need any type of license for strategy game website?

Tags: licensing

I am developer and owner of a online strategy game website (like travian.com).

**Game Scenario:**

Game have map where player creates cities then build buildings and recruits troops and attack other players cities.

I am willing to sell golds (golds refers to selling item) which provide points to players.

Can I need any type of license.

If needed, where can I get it?

And how much will cost it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no license. However, once you make money from whatever you do, you will need to pay taxes. And tax laws can be complicated. You should get a lawyer who can explain your country's laws.